# REST API error "CORS preflight channel did not succeed"

Tags: angularjs, api, rest, yii2

I created a RESTapi to insert data into my databse, It's working perfectly on POSTMAN extension, but I'm getting an error on angularjs http post method.

My Restapi code is created in yii2 framework. My code is below,

```
public function actionNew()
 {

  $model = new Apieducation();

  $user_id = $_REQUEST['user_id'];

  $education = $_REQUEST['education'];

  $passing_year = $_REQUEST['passing_year'];

  $institute = $_REQUEST['institute'];


  //$model->attributes=$params;
  $model->user_id = $user_id;
  $model->education = $education;
  $model->passing_year = $passing_year;
  $model->institute = $institute;


  if ($model->save()) {

     header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
     header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
     header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With,content-type");
         echo json_encode(array('status'=>'1','data'=>$model->attributes),JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
           \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
  } 
  else
  {

 $jobs[] = 'failed';
     header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
     header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
     header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With,content-type");
     echo json_encode(array('status'=>'1','data'=>array_filter($jobs)),JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
     \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;

  }

}
```

And My Angularjs function code is,

```
$scope.educationcreate = function() {

     var data = $.param({
            user_id: $scope.data.user_id,
            education: $scope.data.education,
            passing_year: $scope.data.passing_year,
            institute: $scope.data.institute
        });

        var config = {
            headers : {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
            }
        };

        $http.post('http://localhost/basic/web/index.php?r=apieducation/new', data, config)
          .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

            alert('Successfully');
        })
         .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            alert("ERROR");
        });

      };
```

I got console error,

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at
>   http://localhost/basic/web/index.php?r=apieducation/new. (Reason: CORS
>   preflight channel did not succeed).

How can I solve it?

Comment: which controller are you extending (ActiveController or Rest/Controller) ? and how are your UrlRules configured ? can you add them to the question ?

Comment: also the 8 lines of code following `new Apieducation()` can simply be replaced by a single one: `$model->load(Yii::$app->request->bodyParams, '')`.

Comment: Yii already has built-in actions and filters for what you are building. I suggest checking its [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html) first. otherwise if you want to rebuild what the framework does then you'll need to build the equivalent of [this action too](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/rest/OptionsAction.php) to answer preflight requests.

Comment: class ApieducationController extends \yii\rest\ActiveController

Comment: i didn't add URL rules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Cors filter to solve this error,

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'corsFilter' => [
            'class' => Cors::className(),
            'cors' => [
                // restrict access to
                'Origin' => ['*'],
                'Access-Control-Request-Method' => ['POST', 'GET'],
                // Allow only POST and PUT methods
                'Access-Control-Request-Headers' => [' X-Requested-With'],
                // Allow only headers 'X-Wsse'
                'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => true,
                // Allow OPTIONS caching
                'Access-Control-Max-Age' => 3600,
                // Allow the X-Pagination-Current-Page header to be exposed to the browser.
                'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' => ['X-Pagination-Current-Page'],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This was really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

My short solution:

On server side:

```
npm install cors
```

add `app.use(cors({origin: '*'}));` before all route definitions

On client side:
do everything normally

```
$http.get('http://localhost:36912/api/permissions').then(function (response) {
   console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (error) {
   console.error('Status code: ' + error.status);
   console.error('Error message: ' + error.data);
});
```